# Boto3 Authentication in AWS Lambda Runtime Emulator

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on a Python function for AWS Lambda that uses a container image. The function needs to download files from a private S3 bucket owned by my account. Using `s3 = boto3.client("s3")`, the function is able to authenticate and download files when running on AWS. However, if I test the container locally using the Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html), the S3 authentication fails. Is there any way to authenticate the local container image so that I can test without having to upload to the ECR repository and re-deploying the function each time?

Comment: Did you set the environment variables to have valid AWS access, secret, token, and region as they would inside AWS?

Comment: Can't believe I missed this... thank you!